# ContextMenu closing when clicking an inner control

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a textbox with a ContextMenu, the menu contains a tab control. The problem I'm running into is that when I click any of the tab control items to change the visible tab control item the Context Menu gets closed. Any ideas?

I've tried the `ContextMenu_ContextMenuClosing` event but it doesn't appear to catch the event

```
<TextBox x:Name="TestCB4" TextSearch.TextPath="Name" >
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening" 
                     ContextMenuClosing="ContextMenu_ContextMenuClosing"
                     MouseLeftButtonDown="ContextMenu_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                     StaysOpen="True"
                     Background="Transparent" Margin="0">
            <TabControl ContextMenuClosing="TabControl_ContextMenuClosing" Margin="0">
                <TabItem Header="User Space">
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Margin="10,2,2,2">
                        <Button Content="_Select" Margin="1"
                                Command="{Binding Path=SelectVendorCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ucFindVendorCtrl, Path=VendorListView.SelectedItems}" />
                        <Button Content="_Add To User Space" Margin="1"
                                Command="{Binding Path=AddVendorToUserSpaceCommand}"
                                Width="120"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ucFindVendorCtrl, Path=VendorListView.SelectedItems}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Find">
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Margin="10,2,2,2">
                        <Button Content="_Select" Margin="1"
                                Command="{Binding Path=SelectVendorCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ucFindVendorCtrl, Path=VendorListView.SelectedItems}" />
                        <Button Content="_Add To User Space" Margin="1"
                                Command="{Binding Path=AddVendorToUserSpaceCommand}"
                                Width="120"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ucFindVendorCtrl, Path=VendorListView.SelectedItems}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the TabControl does not *handle* the propagation of the MouseLeftButtonDown routed events, and so the ContextMenu catches it, and closes.

If that's the case, then the solution is rather simple. Just wrap the TabControl in a ContentControl, and catch the event MouseLeftButtonDown on the ContentControl. In the event handler do `e.Handled = true;`
This way the ContextMenu would have no way of knowing that the user has clicked on the TabControl.

Answer (score 1):

try to put your tabcontrol inside a menuItem like the example:

```
<ContextMenu>
<MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="true">
<MenuItem.Header>
...your TabControl
</MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

I hope that it can be helpful.